# Single Photon emission from positronium in strong magnetic fields; how is momentum conserved?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, positronium

I recently came across a [paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1978Ap%26SS..58...83C&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf) (which I will not describe in detail, however, the authors examine the probability of positronium producing a single photon, while under the influence of a strong magnetic field).

The paper insinuates that momentum is still conserved here, but it is conserved through the influence of the magnetic field. What truly astounds me is that as a magnetic field grows stronger (there is a table in the paper, which I will not post, as it could violate copyright laws), the chances of observing a single photon emission surpasses that even of a multiple photon emission. Eventually, it can become highly unlikely to witness anything other than a single photon emission.

How does the strengthening of a magnetic field help conserve momentum, and how does this phenomenon eventually, hinder tremendously, the outcome of a multiple photon emission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the details *are* important. From the abstract in your link of the paper we see that:

1) it is a publication from 1978

2) it calculates rates for positronium annihilation in the very high magnetic fields found in astrophysical situations,  10^12 Gauss

It explicitly states that the momentum contribution comes from the magnetic field.

In the relevant Feynman  diagram  for this annihilation, one of the two photons in the annihilation  of positronium

[image: postironium annihilation]

> A Feynman diagram showing the mutual annihilation of a bound state electron positron pair into two photons.

is [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle), emerging from the strong magnetic field.

The real gamma carries the energy of annihilation of both e+e-, and the virtual balances the momentum, taking the energy from the magnetic field. There is nothing esoteric about this as magnetic fields are dependent on matter particles, electrons , ions in the plasma in space, and they can collectively pick up any rebound momentum, [this reference](http://gr.physics.ncsu.edu/files/babson_ajp_77_826_09.pdf) is interesting on "hidden momenta".

The calculation shows that this is feasible and if one googles there are a number of recent papers on this channel.

Comment: Thank you, I really enjoyed that paper. Our universe never ceases to amaze me.